# Spring boot component scan does not recognize qualifier annotation for different beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have been noticing something weird with the example of using the Bridge design pattern with Spring boot. To overcome the issues of having two beans of the same type in the classpath, I am using Qualifier annotation. However, for some reason, it does not work without using a wildcard for component scan.

Color.java

```
package com.example.bridge;

public interface Color {

  String fill();
}
```

Blue.java

```
package com.example.bridge;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service("Blue")
public class Blue implements Color {
  @Override
  public String fill() {
    return "Color is Blue";
  }
}
```

Red.java

```
package com.example.bridge;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service("Red")
public class Red implements Color {
  @Override
  public String fill() {
    return "Color is Red";
  }
}
```

Shape.java

```
package com.example.bridge;

public abstract class Shape {
  protected Color color;

  public Shape(Color color){
    this.color = color;
  }

  abstract public String draw();
}
```

Square.java

```
package com.example.bridge;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class Square extends Shape {

  public Square(Color color) {
    super(color);
  }

  @Override
  public String draw() {
    return "Square drawn. " + color.fill();
  }
}
```

Triangle.java

```
package com.example.bridge;

@Service
public class Triangle extends Shape {

  public Triangle(Color color) {
    super(color);
  }

  @Override
  public String draw() {
    return "Triangle drawn. " + color.fill();
  }
}
```

BridgeApplication.java

```
package com.example.bridge;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.example.bridge")
public class BridgeApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(BridgeApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
package com.example.bridge;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class BridgeController {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("Red")
  private Color red;

  @GetMapping("/red")
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
  public String redSquare() {
    Shape square = new Square(red);
    return square.draw();
  }

}
```

This project fails to start with the following exception:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-04-14 20:52:52.839 ERROR 9689 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.bridge.Square required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - Blue: defined in file [IdeaProjects/test-bridge-design/target/classes/com/example/bridge/Blue.class]
    - Red: defined in file [IdeaProjects/test-bridge-design/target/classes/com/example/bridge/Red.class]


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

Ok, now let's change the base package for the component scan to use `"com.example.*"`. The same issue.

Now, if I change the base package to be `"com.example.bridge.*"` it works and the application can be started. Technically, I don't need to set the wildcard for the base package and it should pick up all the beans recursively. Also, I don't understand what the difference between `"com.example.bridge.*"` and `"com.example.*"` is.

Comment: You said it works... but which color has been injected in `Square` ? I don't see any primary or qualifier in your code...

Comment: @CodeScale I have added the controller part. In this case, it returns the red square as expected.

Comment: I don't understand why you define the `Square ` as spring bean et init this type in the controller manually `Shape square = new Square(red);` Like this `Square` does not need to be a spring bean...

Answer (score 1):

You got this error because when spring loads the application context it finds that `Square` is a spring bean and so tries to inject a Color. As it found 2impl it generates an error.

The injection of color is only working on controller because you qualified the injection point -> 
`@Autowired
 @Qualifier("Red")
 private Color red;`

As you init the `Square` type manually inside the controller `Shape square = new Square(red);` you don't need the `@Service`on the `Square` type

UPDATED

Concerning package-scan this `com.example.bridge` and this `com.example.bridge.**` are actually the same.

Comment: Actually, the manual initialization was a leftover from an attempt I had to understand why I am having this issue. Otherwise, you are right no injection would be required in that case. Regardless of how the objects are being initialized, the application only works if the component scan is referring to the basic package as "com.example.bridge.*"

Comment: just updated my answer.  But as-is it is normal that it doesn't work because you have no `@Qualifier` on the square type... here it is not a problem of component scanning.

Comment: That's correct, both "com.example.bridge" and "com.example.bridge.*" should work the same, but for some reason in this example "com.example.bridge.*" only works. Also, regarding the error, it actually complains about the constructor of Square which accepts a type of Color. It complains that there are two beans of type Color and it cannot distinguish them at the time of initialization of Square. So are you saying that the only solution to this is to manually initialize Square, and Square cannot be injected at all?

Comment: You have 2 solutions.... either inject `Square` but you have to inject a qualified `Color` in it (red or blue impl). But I think it is not the idea of `GOF Bridge pattern`. Or you inject the Color in your controller and create the square manually. And so you could create square with any color. Last option is to create class `RedSquare` and `BlueSquare` and inject into them the corresponding `Color` with corresponding `@Qualifier`... but this last option is not `bridge pattern` compliant because the explosion of classes...